# How to avoid JQuery animation spam?

Tags: jquery

I got the below code and I would like to know how could I avoid from animation spamming. I mean with this, if you spam `hovers` inside the box it will queue all of the animations. Sometimes it could be accidentally that you hover twice and it seems annoying that the box queues all the animations.

```
<div class="desc">ventore veritatis et quasi architecto...</div>
```

```js
$(".desc").hover(function () {
    var el = $(this),
        curHeight = el.height(),
        autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
    el.height(curHeight).animate({
        height: autoHeight + 20
    }, 500);
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)'
    });
},
function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: 100
    }, 150);
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.6)'
    });
});
```

```css
.desc {
    height:150px;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I would like any ideas for this. For example when `hovered` this box, the `hover` animation would be disabled for 2 seconds. How could I do this?

I want this because I have another 3 boxes like this and it gets annoying. Not a big problem though.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqxonbnu/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to stop the animation chaining by using `.stop()`.

You add it in both functions before the animation to clear the queue like in the below example.

```
$(".desc").hover(function () {
    var el = $(this),
        curHeight = el.height(),
        autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();

    el.stop(true); // end before starting again

    el.height(curHeight).animate({
        height: autoHeight + 20
    }, 500);
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)'
    });
}, function () {
    var el = $(this);
    el.stop(true); // end before starting again

    el.animate({
        height: 100
    }, 150);
    el.animate({
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.6)'
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wqxonbnu/1/)

Only one parameter means to clear the queue but it will not directly go to end animation state.
[Read the documentation for more](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)